# How should I return a notification message using ajax?

Tags: magento-1, ajax

I have an ajax request and I want to display a notice or an error message. I want to use the addNotice or addError function. This is my code:

```
$update =  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Notice message');
$response = Mage::app()->getResponse();
$response->setHttpResponseCode(200);
$json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($update);
$response->setBody($json);
```

I know that I cannot add in the jsonEncode the addNotice function message, but is there another way to do that?  I know that I could send a simple message, but i want to use these functions: `addNotice` and `addError`.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use following into your controller

```
$success = true;
$message = 'massage';
$result = compact('success', 'message');

$response_array = json_encode($result);        
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $response_array;
exit;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code returns a message. I mentioned that I do not want to send a simple message, I want to use somehow those function addnotice or adderror. Is that possible ? thx in advance

Comment: Yes you can adderror using following

Add below code into your top of template :

<div id="messages" style="display: none; margin: 5px 0;">
    <div class="messages"></div>        
</div>

And add following code into ajax jquery script:

jQuery('#messages .messages').html('<div class="message message-error" id="ajax-status">'+response.message+'</div>');

Using this you are able to show your error massage which is return from ajax request.

Thanks